# How do I find my computer model through dxdiag?

Tags: windows-7

I cannot find my computer label. I tried checking what is the mode through dxdiag, but in the "System Model" label it says "all series" which is very unhelpful.

Comment: Why do you believe that your "computer model" should be in dxdiag and/or it should be anything except what is being displayed?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this information isn't actually required and won't affect anything except the dxdiag screen. If you built your own PC, it won't necessarily be filled in. If you purchased a computer from a manufacturer, they tend to put a model name in there.

In terms of finding out the model, it may be an idea to check any receipts for the computer. Is there a reason you need to find out? Perhaps you are actually looking to find out which hardware is in the computer instead?

To change what is displayed, it's stored in this [registry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755256(v=ws.11).aspx) key: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SystemInformation`. If you access this via `regedit.exe` you should see a few keys, one if which will be called `SystemProductName`.

However there's always a chance that this will get overwritten when you reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **RUN** and enter **msinfo32** and you should be able to see it in the information page.